# What's the cause of these characters when I pull content from the database?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, encoding

I'm pulling some content from my database and when I display it, I am getting some random characters occasionally dispersed throughout the content. I am seeing a lot of Â where spaces were/are. I'm also getting â€™ in some places.

The characters don't appear when I view in phpMyAdmin. How do I encode the content correctly? Is it something I should do BEFORE I insert the content or is it something I do when I am displaying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What character set is the data stored in?

For example, if the data is stored as UTF-8, then when displaying the data, you need to make sure the page encoding is set to UTF-8 as well.

If it is stored in some other character set, then set the page encoding as appropriate.

You can do this by passing appropriate headers:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Or letting the browser know in your document:

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8">
```

And in HTML5:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Comment: For some reason, `<meta charset="utf-8" />` works, but `<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8">` doesn't, any idea why?

Comment: `<meta charset="utf-8" />` is for HTML5, and `<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8">` is for HTML4. Are you using the HTML5 doctype?

Comment: no, I'm just doing testing in a view with no header attached, so there is no doctype or anything declared.

Comment: It is possible that `<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8">` isn't working because you did not define a valid doc type. Try defining one and see if it works. Personally, I would use the HTML5 one as that is backwards compatible with older browsers too.

Answer (score 1):

That's UTF-8 being misinterpreted as CP1252. Make sure all the appropriate headers are in place.

```
>>> print u'â€™'.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')
’
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the best thing would be to work on utf-8 on your files/database (or at least the same encoding in all places).

Please check what do you have under $db['default']['char_set'] and $db['default']['dbcollat'] on your application/config/database.php and what encoding you are using in your views/html. If you see the data correctly on PMA, then maybe the problem is in your views.

Try to use [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) or [utf8_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) when you print your text.